# View all the css used of a certain container

Tags: html, css, debugging

I would like to view the css used of a certain container..

I use chrome inspect element often. I also use firebug occasionally.

Is there a way to view all the css code used within a container with one click..  I mean I'm talking about all the children css too

```
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="inner1">
    </div>
    <div class="inner2">
    </div>
   <div class="inner3">
    </div>
   <div class="inner4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now is it possible to view all the css code (including children) of `someclass` ?

Comment: not that I know of, I don't see the need for something like this since there could a lot of children per container and the amount of css you would get back would be enormous and hard to debug.

Comment: But we can use javascripts to generate the codes. Right?

Comment: Using js to generate the css? I don't know I would imagine you can do just about anything with js but I honestly don't know since I have never done it

Comment: No you misunderstood. I am js noob. Thats why I asked you that question. I have used a firefox addon called dust me selectors. We can see all the used css of a page using that tool. But I just want the code of certain container.

Comment: you want the css code for that certain container and all of its children right? I don't know of any addons that does that

Answer (score 0):

[image]

At the very bottom of your Chrome tools, this is displayed. You can click parents, children, etc to view the relevant code in the sidebar.

Comment: You really understood my question?

Comment: @Giri I thought so... Maybe not? I thought you were looking for a way to move up and down the dom, viewing the relevant CSS along the way.